# Explain the solution of the "Reverse an array" task from the Eloquent JS book

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could anyone provide a clear explanation on what did they do in the example below? It is really confusing.

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
    var old = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = old;
  }
  return array;
}

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

Comment: Run through a few steps of the code, i = 0 -> 2.... it is a straightforward algorithm that isn't particular to any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop iterates through the first half of the array, up to but not including the middle value for an array with an odd number of elements (since the middle value stays in the same place when the array is reversed).

The first time through the loop, the values of the first and last positions in the array are reversed.

The second time through the loop, the values of the second and second last positions in the array are reversed.

etc...

Answer (score 1):

It's not very complicated really, just get a bit of paper, write down 5 boxes for the array and then step through the program in your head working out what happens at each step. For example:

```
1,2,3,4,5
i=0
old=1
5,2,3,4,5
5,2,3,4,1
i=1
```

Continue like that, I got you started.